# Cocos2dx open gl issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am making android version of cocos2dx iOS game. In iOS few gl apis were not supproted by cocos2dx for that we used the native iOS apis. Now when I am running the same code base on andorid those non-supported APIs are giving error. followiing is the code which runs purfact on Xcode project and gived error (mentioned in fron of respective lines) elcipse:

```
glPushMatrix(); //ERROR: 'glPopMatrix' was not declared in this scope
glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0); //ERROR: 'glPopMatrix' was not declared in this scope

float angle = 360.0 / sparkleNum;

int idx, opacity;
idx = index % FIREWORK_TYPE_NUM;

opacity = (1.0 - step) * 255;

for(int i = 0; i < sparkleNum; ++i)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(i * angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //ERROR: 'glPopMatrix' was not declared in this scope
    glTranslatef(0.0, dist, 0.0);
    glScalef(scalar, scalar, scalar);//ERROR: 'glPopMatrix' was not declared in this scope

    firework[idx]->setOpacity(opacity);
    firework[idx]->draw();

    glPopMatrix(); //ERROR: 'glPopMatrix' was not declared in this scope
}

glPopMatrix(); //ERROR: 'glPopMatrix' was not declared in this scope
```

help me remove these error and successfully use the gl apis.

Answer (score 0):

```
kmGLPushMatrix();
kmGLPopMatrix();
```

Gles2.0 doesn't have these functions, try to use kazmath instead.